# Ввод по маске uri средствами jquery

Tags: jquery

Как сделать маску при вводе uri. Мне нужно чтобы все адреса начинались http://www, или просто были валидными

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Можно пример?

Comment: есть инпут, в который вводится адрес сайта, при вводе google.com, в начало ссылки надо добавить http://
вопрос заключается в том, как осуществить эту проверку и добавить http://

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой плагин к jQuery.
Вот [ссылка](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) на него, а [вот](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) дока. В доке там и примеры есть. Вебсайта правда нету, но по аналогии замутить очень просто.